# Installing JPGraph with Hostgator website

Tags: php, jpgraph

I've been trying to install jpgraph to my hostgator website but there's a problem somewhere which I can't figure out.  There's a few things which are causing me to think the problem could be in several places;

first, when unpacking the file to my desktop ready to put into the server I get an error of 'The destination folder is a subfolder of the source folder', for this I just click continue and it seems to be OK.

This unpacks the folders which I rename to jpgraph as per the example FAQ on http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch02.html#id2475509

second, when I look at the examples the original code is [code]`require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');` though the file structure is such that it should be jpgraph/src/jpgraph.php though even when I update the file structre the file doesn't work.

Third, I noticed when looking at different files some of the file structures reference jpgraph 3.xxx(version)/jpgraph.php but others use the short form jpgraph/jpgraph.php

I can't find any reasonable installation (see:Any) installation tutorials from youtube and the other thread on SO wasn't very helpful as it was solved in the background.

Comment: What does your error message say exactly? Do you get a php error or a completely different error?

Comment: the error is 
Warning: require_once(jpgraph/src/jpgraph.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/maudise/public_html/jpgraph/jpgraph/src/Examples/example0.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'jpgraph/src/jpgraph.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php53/lib/php') in /home/maudise/public_html/jpgraph/jpgraph/src/Examples/example0.php on line 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment it looks like your php script just cannot find the jpgraph scripts, p.e. wrong path.

Try something like this, if you're using jpgraph as the graph lib of your choice:

```
$jpgraph_dir = '/your/path/to/your/jpgraph/';
require_once($jpgraph_dir . 'src/jpgraph.php');
```

If you still receive this error message, your path is just wrong.

Comment: that's actually amazing!  It works perfectly, my only concern now is that i'll have to go and update all the files, is there a quick way to do it?

Comment: I am a little confused why putting $jpgraph_dir = '/home/maudise/public_html/jpgraph/' and into the require once for it to work?  Appreciate the original question is answered (I've tried to add upticks but need 15 rep) but if you have any idea?

Comment: Well, you have to tell your script where this file is exactly. If your script cannot find it, you'll receive the error you've encountered. My short approach just makes it a little bit more obvious. You shouldn't need to update the example files, since they're working with relative path. Another approach would be to place jpgraph into your php directory (usually php searches there too if it cannot find an include or require).